# Binding a ListView with a List coming from ViewModel

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, binding, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app using Mvvm format for school and need help with something.

So I'm trying to make a ListView with items comming from a List that is in my ViewModel.

Here is some code :

**MainScreenViewModel.cs**

```
using EasySleep.Model;
using EasySleep.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Template10.Mvvm;
using Template10.Services.NavigationService;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace EasySleep.ViewModels
{
    class MainScreenViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        ServiceApi serviceApi;

        public List<Offer> TestList { get; set; }

        public MainScreenViewModel()
        {
            serviceApi = new ServiceApi();
            TestList = new List<Offer>();
            TestList.Add(new Offer(1, true, null, "Decription de dingue", 3));
            TestList.Add(new Offer(3, false, null, "Decription de fou", 6));
            TestList.Add(new Offer(7, true, null, "Decription de perdu", 9));
        }

        public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void GoToMainScreen() =>
            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainScreen));

        public void GotoSettings() =>
            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 0);

        public void GotoAbout() =>
            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.SettingsPage), 1);

        public void Logout()
        {
            ServiceApi.Token = null;
            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.MainPage));
        }

    }
}
```

**MainScreenPage.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="AllActiveOffersListView" 
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestList}"
                  Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

**Offer.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EasySleep.Model
{
    public class Offer
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public int MaxPeople { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
        public String OwnerId { get; set; }

        public Offer (int id, Boolean isActive, List<Photo> photos, string description, int maxPeople)
        {
            Id = id;
            IsActive = isActive;
            Photos = photos;
            Description = description;
            MaxPeople = maxPeople;
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public Offer(string description, int id, Boolean isActive, Location loc, int locationId, int maxPeople, ApplicationUser owner, string ownerId)
        {
            Id = id;
            IsActive = isActive;
            Description = description;
            MaxPeople = maxPeople;
            Location = loc;
            LocationId = locationId;
            Owner = owner;
            OwnerId = ownerId;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Description + LocationId;
        }

    }
}
```

Can you help me binding these things please ?

I edited to add Offer.cs model

Comment: Its pretty much the same with a Listview, so here you have a detailed explanation: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/

Comment: Also you might want to use an ObservableCollection, since the binding does not refresh on a normal list upon adding elements

Comment: @Curunir Well this tip is using code behind, I want to do everything from the viewmodel.
The list gonne be fully loaded before the view and there won't be any option to add dynamycally ellements

Comment: @EllinPlay Have you tried to put bindings in the DataTemplate content, like this: <TextBlock Text="{Binding [PROPERTYNAME]}"> where [PROPERTYNAME] is some property of the Offer class?

Comment: @Jogy I tried, but I think a need to refer the model somewhere as a property of DataTemplate but I don't find the way to do this

Comment: The DataTemplate will have as DataContext the items in the list. So if the list is correctly bound, you don't have to do anything. (That is, if you use the old Binding syntax, if you want to use the new x:Bind, then you have to specify the object type in the DataTemplate)

Comment: Do you want use `x:Bind`? We need to set `x:DataType` in the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: @Jogy
I don't care what syntax to use, I tried using {Binding Description} in the Text property of TextBlock (Description being a property from Offer model) but I get a error he can't find Description property. 
That's why I supposed I need to refer Offer model somewhere

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT I tried it aswell, my offer is in a Model namespace, how to refer him ? Maybe I did it the wrong way

Comment: @EllinPlay You should try to see if the ListView item source is set properly - remove the ListView.ItemTemplate tag, and run the app - then the ListView should display a list with the name of the class that is in it's collection. If it is the correct collection, try to add the DisplayMemberPath propery in the ListView and set it to "Description"

Comment: @Jogy Well, it's showing me the name of the class but DisplayMemberPath doesn't seem to be working with "Description" or "{Binding Description}"

Comment: @EllinPlay Can you show the definition of the Offer class? Maybe there is something wrong with it, the bindings or the DisplayMemberPath should be working

Comment: @Jogy I don't think so but I edited my question and added the Offer model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />` should work, there is no need to specify anything else. 
I created an empty Template10 app and put there your model, and it works.

Here is the main page xaml:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <controls:PageHeader x:Name="pageHeader"
                         Content="Main Page"
                         RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                         RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                         RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" />

    <RelativePanel EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo.IsTargetElement="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                   RelativePanel.Below="pageHeader">

        <!--  content  -->
  <ListView x:Name="AllActiveOffersListView" 
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestList}"
              Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>

</RelativePanel>

</RelativePanel>
```

You can download the full working project from http://personal.sirma.bg/Jogy/download/WindowsApp1.zip and check if it will work for you, then see what is different between your project and mine.

Jogy